# How to include image in slideshow from array (dynamic slideshow)

Tags: javascript, php, html, slideshow

I have a php code that processed some data and generates some images. The number of images varies depending on search condition.

Now I want to display them, but do not want the page to be flooded with images.
Is there a way to get those at one place where clicking next button will show the next image, as we see in slideshows.

I know to imbed a slideshow. But I am facing trouble running it from a loop.

```
foreach($dd1_tmp as $tmpid){
  $imgFileName='../Images/tmp_plots/'.$tmpid.'.png';
  if(file_exists("$imgFileName")){
  echo "$tmpid";
  echo "<img src=\"$imgFileName\"; style=\"width:42%\"/>";}
}
```

In above code I have names in the array "$dd1_tmp".

please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the trick is the let the image change after x seconds. This will be the information you are looking for:
[w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)

[w3schools slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)